# Error while drying jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to run my jasmine tests for multiple inputs using data providers. For this I am trying to use jasmine-data-provider package using the following link:

http://blog.jphpsf.com/2012/08/30/drying-up-your-javascript-jasmine-tests

But when I run my test, I am getting an error which I am unable to resolve.

My test:

```
using("multiple inputs",["a","b"], function(input) {
    it("should check the header for: ", function () {
        mainPage.screen(input, 'cdcd');
        expect(mainPage.mainHeader.getText()).toEqual(mainData.mainHeaderText);
    });
});
```

Error I am getting:

```
 TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'multiple inputs'
```

Comment: does it work for normal spec? (by normal, I mean without using `using`)

Comment: yes, it does work

Comment: and you do have implementation of custom `using` function as mentioned in the blog too right?

Comment: No actually, I thought this will be used from npm package for jasmine-data-provider that I installed. This one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider

Comment: I found the issue there! Added the same as answer. Funny how we make such mistakes in hurry! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the catch: the [blog](http://blog.jphpsf.com/2012/08/30/drying-up-your-javascript-jasmine-tests) you mentioned had it made for jasmine v1.2 only but [jasmine-data-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider) package is for later versions of jasmine. **But**, with a syntax change!

As mentioned in the examples on npm module page, `using` function **expects the array of inputs as first argument** as opposed to the one mentioned in blog-post.

Which explains why you got the following error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'multiple inputs'
```

Here's the example snippet that should work:

```
var using = require('jasmine-data-provider');

...

using(["a","b"], function(input) {
    it("should check the header for: ", function () {
        mainPage.screen(input, 'cdcd');
        expect(mainPage.mainHeader.getText()).toEqual(mainData.mainHeaderText);
    });
});
```